# Use my sript when using MasterPages in ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, scripting, master-pages

I have Chat.aspx page which is loaded with a master page (site.Master).

I have a script that does not work when placed on the Chat.aspx page. Thus i tried to apply the same script in the master page (in the script manager) as follows:

**

```
        <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/chatQuery.js" />
                 ...
```

**

And under master page head tag as below:

```
<head runat="server">
  <link href="/Content/Interlude.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/chatQuery"></script>
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
```

Nonetheless my `chatQuery.js` does not seem to work either way i try.

Comment: Your `src` attribute is missing the `.js` in `chatQuery.js` (MasterPage head)

Comment: have you missed the extension?

Comment: Your first code snippet should work provided you have a `Scripts` folder under the web site root  and also if that folder contains a file by the name of `chatQuery.js`. Make sure that the file under `Scripts` folder has that file with `js` extension.

Comment: Also, make sure that the `ScriptManager` control is the first control after the `<form` tag in your master page.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the `ScriptManager` is the first control after the form tag in your master page as in code below.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/chatQuery.js" />
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

*Also, there needs to be a `Scripts` folder under the root folder of your website* containing a file called `chatQuery.js`. If this folder exists under the root of your website but the file with `js` extension does not exist, then the script will NOT get loaded when you render your page in a browser.

If you follow the above instructions, then you don't need to use the second approach where you are inserting a script reference in the head section of your page. You have to **always** give the full file name of the JavaScript file including its extension. So `chatQuery` is wrong, but `chatQuery.js` is right.

Answer (score 0):

Your are missing a `.js` in the script path thus your chatQuery does not work.

The way you have it is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/chatQuery"></script>
```

The way it is supposed to be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/chatQuery.js"></script>
```

Also make sure it is not conflicting with any other scripts you might be running on your web site/

Comment: Well seen, it was my mistake when copying to the site, but even correcting this error is not reading the script file

Comment: Can you show the full master page, and all the scripts you are referencing. Also do you have a reference to the actual jquery library:

Comment: <script src="/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>